# How to copy a range of cells and paste values to two different worksheets?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of data on Sheet2 that links it to Sheet1 (Sheet1 is formatted and linked by Sheet2 using `=if(Sheet2$x$x="","",Sheet2$x$x)`; this way any data put into the range C13:G62 of Sheet2 shows up in Sheet1 range C13:G62. The beginning portion on the code works to move JUST the data in the specified range to the BATCH file Sheet3 and finds the last row pasting the values from Sheet1 without copying the formulas. It was made this way so I can delete data on Sheet2 to wipe Sheet1 clean but still have all the backup data on one Sheet3.

Anyway, the problem lies when I tried to manipulate the code to copy all contents on Sheet1 (to DUPLICATE SHEET1) to another sheet at the end of the workbook:

```
 Sheets(Sheet1).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
 ActiveSheet.Name = _
 InputBox("Name of the New WorkSheet")
```

This allowed me to name the sheet which was great. However by creating multiple variations of code it will not move the DATA in the RANGE to the newly created Sheet4 (there is no data). In one iteration of code I was able to get Sheet1 to copy and make Sheet4 at the end of the work book with no data in the range but have the cursor land in cell C13, the starting point for pasting just the values, and when I left click the mouse in that cell to "paste values" it would paste the values that I was trying to paste. However, either way I rearranged the code, the data would always be copied but would never paste to the Sheet4 range.

Here I have posted one variation of the code IN WHICH IT STILL WILL NOT PASTE THE VALUES TO SHEET4 (THE NEWLY CREATED SHEET) but still copies to the BATCH FILE. What am I missing here?

```
Dim s1Sheet As Worksheet
Dim s2Sheet As Worksheet
Dim source As String
Dim target As String
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim rngTargetStart As Range
source = "Invoice"
target = "TOTAL_INVOICE"
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
Set s1Sheet = Sheets(source)
Set s2Sheet = Sheets(target)
Set rngSource = s1Sheet.Range("C13:G62")
Set rngTargetStart = s2Sheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
'Set rngTargetFinish = ws1.Range("C"  & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
rngTargetStart.Resize(rngSource.Rows.Count, rngSource.Columns.Count).Value = rngSource.Value
'rngTargetFinish.Resize(rngSource.Rows.Count, rngSource.Columns.Count).Value = rngSource.Value
'Set target = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("B13:G63")
copy_non_formulas source:=rngSource, target:=rngTargetStart
 ' copy_non_formulas source:=Range("B13:G63"), target:=Range("B70:G109")     Unhighlight
 ' copy_non_formulas source:=Range("B13:G63"), target:=Range("B13:G63")      Unhighlight



'===Copies Sheet to End of WorkBook & Pastes Values======
Sheets(source).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = _
InputBox("Name of the New WorkSheet")
Range("C13:G62").ClearContents
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C13:G62")
rng.ClearContents
Dim s3Sheet As Worksheet
Dim rngTargetStart2 As Range
Set s3Sheet = Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Set rngTargetStart2 = s3Sheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
rngTargetStart2.Resize(rngSource.Rows.Count, rngSource.Columns.Count).Value = rngSource.Value
copy_non_formulas2 source:=rngSource, target2:=rngTargetStart2
copy_non_formulas2 source:=Range("C13:G62"), target2:=Range("C13:G62")
```

This is an Integrated Public Sub

```
copy_non_formulas(source As Range, target As Range)
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim c As Range

For i = 1 To source.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To source.Columns.Count
        Set c = source(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:=j)
        If Left(c.Formula, 1) <> "=" Then
            target(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:=j).Value = c.Value
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

And another Public Sub for the Second Move

```
copy_non_formulas2(source As Range, target2 As Range)
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim d As Range

For x = 1 To source.Rows.Count
    For y = 1 To source.Columns.Count
        Set d = source(RowIndex:=x, ColumnIndex:=y)
        If Left(d.Formula, 1) <> "=" Then
            target2(RowIndex:=x, ColumnIndex:=y).Value = d.Value
        End If
    Next y
Next x
```